# Best option to draw thousands of triangles

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, graphics

I'm developing a small 2D triangulation application and I need to draw on the screen thousands os triangles and points (may reach 500k points) and I need to be able to pan and zoom using mouse middle button.

The application must be WPF

I found many way to do that, but I would like to ask more experienced users which would be best:

1) OpenGL (SharpGL or OpenTK): looks like it's the best option so far, but I never worked with openGL and I'm also not sure how easy it would be to implement

2) WPF DrawingVisual class: as far as I read I have to implement my won event handlings for my zoom and pan needs

3) WPF drawing on canvas: tried this first but application stared to loose performance at 25k points + lines

4) WriteableBitmapEx: could'n find any good examples out there so I'm not sure of its capabilites. I saw there are some shape drawing features, but does it have a good performance and the pan and zoom would be easy to implement?

Comment: [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/03/08/performant-virtualized-wpf-canvas.aspx) might be useful for you.

Comment: Use OpenGL.  It's pretty easy to get basic triangle drawing going.  Just hunt around for some introductory tutorials on creating triangle vertex buffers with GL in WPF.  Camera stuff won't be a big deal, cos you can just use orthographic projection (`glOrtho`).